# Network unreachable when using Google Maps Geocode API in Google Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, okhttp, dataflow, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the Google Maps Geocode API (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java) in a Dataflow job. My DoFn prepares the GeoApiContext at Setup. The process element function is done like so:

```java
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String address = c.element().get("Address").toString();
        String id = c.element().get("Id").toString();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        try {
            GeocodingResult[] results = GeocodingApi.newRequest(this.geocodeContext).address(address).language("pt-BR").components(ComponentFilter.country("BR")).await();
            if(results.length == 0) {
                TableRow outputRow = new TableRow();
                outputRow.set("Id", id);
                c.output(outputRow);
            } else {
                for(GeocodingResult r : results) {
                    TableRow outputRow = convertTableRow(gson.toJson(r).toString());
                    outputRow.set("Id", id);
                    c.output(outputRow);
                }
            }
        } catch(ApiException e) {
            LOGGER.error("ApiException on address: {}", address, e);
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            LOGGER.error("InterruptedException on address: {}", address, e);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("IOException on address: {}", address, e);
        }
    }
```

This code worked fine locally, but when deployed to dataflow it throws a network error:

```java
exception: "java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to maps.googleapis.com/2607:f8b0:4001:c05:0:0:0:5f:443
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:265)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:183)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:224)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.findHealthyConnection(ExchangeFinder.java:108)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ExchangeFinder.find(ExchangeFinder.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Transmitter.newExchange(Transmitter.java:169)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:94)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:88)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:142)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:117)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:229)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:172)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:591)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:130)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:263)
    ... 22 more
```

I've ensured that the VM spawned has internet access and I can even ping the maps.googleapis.com endpoint from inside the container:

```
USER@test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l ~ $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b2fd123138aa        3a1cb7aedd54                                      "/opt/google/dataflo…"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_healthchecker_dataflow-test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l_default_5648e9815f2ca5beea8b0eb945e12d1f_0
086e36c3dd23        4127911f4769                                      "/opt/google/dataflo…"   6 minutes ago       Up 5 minutes                            k8s_vmmonitor_dataflow-test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l_default_5648e9815f2ca5beea8b0eb945e12d1f_0
2890fa415af5        664bd8972b23                                      "/opt/google/dataflo…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                            k8s_shuffle_dataflow-test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l_default_5648e9815f2ca5beea8b0eb945e12d1f_0
eea757bf6be7        gcr.io/cloud-dataflow/v1beta3/beam-java11-batch   "/opt/google/dataflo…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                            k8s_java-batch_dataflow-test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l_default_5648e9815f2ca5beea8b0eb945e12d1f_0
b636784118f5        k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1                              "/pause"                 6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes                            k8s_POD_dataflow-test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l_default_5648e9815f2ca5beea8b0eb945e12d1f_0
lucas@test-geocode-07020834-qmrj-harness-3k2l ~ $ docker exec -it eea /bin/sh
# ping maps.googleapis.com                                               
PING maps.googleapis.com (172.217.214.95) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.214.95: icmp_seq=1 ttl=115 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.214.95: icmp_seq=2 ttl=115 time=1.28 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.214.95: icmp_seq=3 ttl=115 time=1.15 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.214.95: icmp_seq=4 ttl=115 time=1.41 ms
^C
--- maps.googleapis.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.089/1.235/1.414/0.131 ms
#
```

Regarding versions, I'm using the latest beam version (2.22.0) and the latest google maps version (0.14.0).

No idea what else to look at, and any help is appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The problem seems to be the fact that the request is done with an ipv6 address. However, GCE machines seems to have no support for ipv6 and the call simply fails without falling back to ipv4.

Considering that, there doesn't seem to be any way out of this problem:

- Configuring the JVM to prefer ipv4 address can't be done with Dataflow (JVM flags are ignored)
- There's also no way to customize the GCE machine (since a base Dataflow image is used)
- The library doesn't seem to open any options to configure ipv4 or ipv6

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify any [network](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#specifying_a_network_and_a_subnetwork) parameters submitting the job? Did you assign external IP addresses for the Dataflow workers?

Comment: Yes, it points correctly to my VPC and its subnetwork. The machines have external IPs but there is a Cloud NAT configured also (don't know if this could interfere somehow). Anyway, as mentioned, I can ssh into the machine and check that internet connectivity is up, so it seems unlikely that it's simply a network or firewall config.

Comment: Can you share discovery results given in the most recent update, composing the answer and helping the further contributors with their research?

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I don't understand what exactly you mean by sharing discovery results. If you can further elaborate, I'll be happy to amend the question with whatever else is needed.

Comment: Apparently, you're trying to connect to `maps.googleapis.com` through IPv6 protocol which is currently unsupported for GCE instances. Would you consider to switch to IPv4?

Comment: Hello @LucasRosa, so did you find the solution to your problem ? I'm having the same

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue come up after upgrading from 2.17 to 2.24 and changing from Java 8 to Java 11.  After trying to fix this on 2.24 and Java 11 I gave up and went back to 8 and it's working now.

I couldn't find it documented anywhere but it looks like the userAgent used is based on that -

When I build the self executable with Java 8, Dataflow shows the userAgent as
Apache_Beam_SDK_for_Java/2.24.0(JRE_8_environment)

and with Java 11 it shows Apache_Beam_SDK_for_Java/2.24.0(JDK_11_environment)